# Como usar o "sync" do Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Recentemente descobri um recurso do `eloquent` chamado `sync`, vi que ele meio que compara os dados passados com os dados que estão no banco de dados e deleta ou insere o que tiver diferente. Queria implementar isso na minha aplicação, mas não entendi como faria.

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
id  id_setor_empresa  id_exame
1   5                 3
2   5                 20
3   5                 17
```

Que armazena quais os exames devem ser feitos pelos funcionários de um setor.

Atualmente quando quando é feita uma edição, eu deleto todos os exames do setor e cadastro os novos. Como posso usar o `sync` para fazer isso de forma mais "limpa"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) está disponível desde a versão 4, e é utilizado apenas em relações muitos para muitos (`belongsToMany`).

Este método é semelhante ao `attach()`, segue explanação:

**attach():**

Utilizado para adicionar uma nova relação na tabela dinâmica.

Exemplo:

```
$setor = Setor::find(5);
$setor->exames()->attach(2);
```

Sua tabela agora ficaria assim:

```
id  id_setor_empresa  id_exame
1   5                 3
2   5                 20
3   5                 17
4   5                 2
```

**sync():**

Utilizado para substituir os dados existentes por os informados via parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
$setor = Setor::find(5);
$setor->exames()->sync([20,10]);
```

Sua tabela agora ficaria assim:

```
id  id_setor_empresa  id_exame
2   5                 20
4   5                 10
```

Neste caso é deletado os dados que não estão no array e insere os que ainda não estão na tabela.